# Including original message in VSTO Outlook addin reply

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

Is there an easy way to programatically create a reply message in a VSTO Outlook addin that includes the original message, with the same look that occurs when clicking on the built-in reply button in Outlook? Or does one need to write code to retrieve the original email properties & text, and format it such that it looks as if the reply was composed by Outlook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

private void Reply(Outlook._MailItem mailItem)
{
    Outlook.Actions actions = mailItem.Actions;
    Outlook.Action action = actions["Reply"];
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(actions);
    action.ReplyStyle = Outlook.OlActionReplyStyle.olIncludeOriginalText;
    Outlook._MailItem response = action.Execute() as Outlook.MailItem;
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(action);
    response.Display();
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(response);
}
```